# No html/css/javascript with Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, html, css, silverlight, ria

If I decided to use Silverlight, does this mean that I'm no longer working with html/css/javascript on the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, but if you want to write a website entirely in Silverlight then no, no more css javascript etc. But in most cases you will write normal website with a silverlight object embedded. The last option is to write a website in asp.net with css/html/javascript, but also write a silverlight object that can interact with the html etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right if you are developing a complete web application in Silverlight.

Silverlight is like developing a desktop application but for the web. You define the UI in XAML and the application code in C#, VB.NET etc.

You still need a web page to deliver the application to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You never work with html/css/javascript on the server side. You can build them on server side, but they usually executed on client side.

Comment: Couldn't you have guessed that I was typing too fast and made a mistake. Why post an answer for that :S